# Manually connecting to a wired network with linux

Tags: linux, networking, router, troubleshooting, wired-networking

I currently only have wired internet via a cable modem connected to an [Airlink 101 ASW105 switch](http://airlink101.com/products/asw105.php). It works fine for my wife's mac. However, my laptop does not connect; I've tried connecting via eth0 and tried creating a new wired connection- but both fail to connect.

It's not a hardware problem with my cables or the network hardware, as my wife's machine has been used to test all cables and ports etc, other than that of my laptop.

So, how can I go about connecting to this network via commands on the terminal?

If you need more information please fire away.

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem. You just say it "does not connect", but don't explain how you tried to connect it or what happened when you tried.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the US, you may need to have a router between the switch and the cable modem that can do nat and dhcp. Most routers nowadays have builtin switches, so it may obviate the use of your switch.

To confirm this, try powering off the wife's mac, then powering on your laptop, if you get an ip address and surf the web, then power on the wife's mac. I'd expect that her mac won't be able to surf if you are (and vice versa). This indicates that the cable modem is only handing out 1 ip address, which means that you'll need a router connected to the cable modem to handle nat.

Good Luck!